# session not working in classic asp on iis server 8

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

My Session variable isn't initialising in classic asp webPages which is hosted on iis server 8,
I have already configured the Session properties in session state feature view as well as in the Debugging Properties of ASP section of IIS server 8,

please help me i m facing this problems after shifting my whole website from Windows server 2008 r2 with IIS7 to Windows server 2012 r2 with IIS8

on IIS 7 i haven't face any issue regarding this session variables initialiasation

any help,would be appriciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable session state under classic asp in IIS7/IIS8.

Open IIS Manager. Navigate to the site you are working on.  On the right double click ASP. Click on Session properties + to show all options.  Change enable session state to true.

Comment: Great.  Its nice to see I am not the only one that deals with Classic asp on a regular basis

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem.**In my case website has no cookie**. I do not use SSL certificate for my websie and exist `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />` code inside `system.web` section . after I change this to `<httpCookies requireSSL="false" />` my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to make sure the variables aren't being initialising:

```
dim i
dim j
j = Session.Contents.Count
Response.Write("Session variables: " & j & "<br>") 
For i=1 to j
  Response.Write(Session.Contents(i) & "<br>") 
Next
```

The code above will show you if there is any variable being initialized and the content of each one.

Answer (score 0):

If session state is ok in the IIS settings, check to make sure that you didn't use `session.Abandon()` because when this method is called, the current Session object is not deleted until all of the script on the current page have been processed. This means that it is possible to access session variables on the same page as the call to Abandon, but not from another Web page and not when you plan to transfer data between two pages by using the session object.